# Mobile OnMouseDown

Tags: unity, android

I have a scene in my game with a bunch of colliders2D. The game is made for android. I want to be able to click on some colliders2D and execute some functions there. So I started with `OnMouseDown` on the gameobjects that I was clicking. Then I had to add a rigidbody2d so this would work. Recently though, the game crashes only when playing that scene once the apk is installed in the middle of the scene. The problem is that I can't get it to crash when on the editor or playing the game remotely with Unity Remote. So I haven't got a clue what the problem is

I think it may be the fact that there are a bunch of colliders2D with onmousedown functions attached to them. I got to that conclusion after some research on the forums. Do you think this maybe causing the random crashes? I can try to attach raycast functions to this objects instead of onmousedown but it seems much more complicated code than onmousedown. Plus it will be such a pain having to go to every single function where I wrote onMouse down, I have removed those on mousedown functions by writing #if UNITY_EDITOR code #endif
but the problems stays there, what can cause an only mobile crash and not on the editor, a performance issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the problem was not onmousedown, but having around 10 canvas in a scene,it seems like mobiles cant handle this I solved it just by dragging all those ui objects into a canvas.